# How do you connect to RDS using lambda and should I be putting queries in there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

My first question is about approach. is this the correct way?

I have a react frontend, I make a call to API gateway => this triggers lambda => lambda makes a DB query => returns to API Gateway => react

secondly, my question is how

I have this lambda code:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host     : RDSINSTANCE,
  user     : USER,
  password : PASSWORD,
  database : DBNAME
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

      connection.query('SELECT * FROM exercises', function (error, results, fields) {

        connection.release();

        if (error) context.fail(error)
        else context.succeed(null, results[0])

      });
    })
}
```

I can confirm when I changed the code to be locally node compliant, it correctly returned me the row I was after, so the RDS is setup correctly as is the javascript code.

however, my lambda is timing out

I added this line: `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` as a few people said that was an issue. however, still timing out

I have also tried using `callback` instead of `context.` but to no avail

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure that your Lambda Runtime limit is set adequately? The code looks fine on first glance, but if the table is huge, this might be a problem.

Comment: @Maurice the table is one row long haha. and my lambda runtime timeout is set to 5 seconds, which seems more than adequate?

Comment: @Maurice do I need to choose a VPC?

Comment: Yes, your lambda should be the same VPC as your RDS instance

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Im new to AWS so Im not sure how to do this. is there a good tutorial I can find? the only one I found so far was python. I would like one using node

Comment: @RedBaron VPC is not really a python or nodeJS matter, you need your Lambda Functions to run in a specific Subnet with specific Security Groups to allow access to the database.

Comment: @Maurice any guidance on this anywhere? I'm still getting timeouts

Comment: it's working. finally. well, it returned null, but that's a start. thanks both for the help! shame this is not documented better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow from API Gateway to Lambda is the correct way.

I advise to use `callback` instead of `context` for passing information back to the caller as that is the officially documented way to do it. <sup>[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback)</sup>

You should consider that the Lambda may have failed to obtain a connection object from the pool and handle that scenario.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err)
            callback(err);

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM exercises', function (error, results, fields) {
            connection.release();

            if (error) callback(error);
            else callback(null, results[0]);
        });
    });
}
```